# Publish existing create-react-app using nwb

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, nwb

I have an existing React application built with create-react-app version 2. I understand that I'll either have to eject it or use a tool like nwb to publish it to npm.

Can I use npm on an existing project? From reading the docs it seems I have to create a new project using the command 'nwb new react-app nwb-thinking-in-react''. But if I already have a project can I just publish using nwb or would I have to copy my files into the newly created project created by the nwb new react-app nwb-thinking-in-react' command.

I'm also interested in how to achieve the above using a project written in TypeScript.

Comment: any update on this ? looking forward to it for react js application tto